# GET URL parameter from code in DNN 7.2

Tags: url-routing, dotnetnuke, url-parameters

I want to get Full URL including URL Parameter in my module code.

For example

From This URL

```
http://Domain/Search-Space-For-Rent/Houston

TabController.CurrentPage.FullUrl
```

Gives me

*//Domain/Search-Space-For-Rent*

only I need to get last parameter from URL (Houston)

I also tried

```
Globals.NavigateURL(this.TabId, this.Request.QueryString["ctl"], UrlUtils.GetQSParamsForNavigateURL());
```

How can I get that?

Answer (score 1):

Typically within DNN you would simply get from the QueryString ex:

```
var myParam = Request.Querystring["paramName"];
```

What parameter name are you using when you build that URL? I would assume you've got a custom URL provider that changing something like "&city=Houston" to be /Houston instead. If that is the case, just grab the querystring paramter called City.

Update:
To get the "Name" of the page, assuming the scenario where Houston is a page in DNN, you could do the following.

```
var tc = new TabController();
var ti = tc.GetTab(TabId);
var pageName = ti.TabName
```

TabId comes from DNN, assuming your module inherits from PortalModuleBase you should have access to it. With that, you can then get the TabInfo from the TabController, and access the properties off that TabInfo object.

Comment: There is no custom URL provider, But I guess with DNN 7.1+ it's built in feature that you can have URLs with trailing routValue same as MVC does. For example my page name in DNN is Search-Space-For-Rent but I have urls like "Search-Space-For-Rent/Houston","Search-Space-For-Rent/Dallas". I dont know the name of querystring parameter

Comment: Ah so that is most likely actually just the Page name, where the Parent Page is "Search-Space-For-Rent" you have another page called Houston. I'll update my answer with how to get the TabName

Answer (score 1):

So I regenerated URL using all query string parameters.

```
 string path = TabController.CurrentPage.FullUrl;

                foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
                {
                    if (key != "TabId" && key != "language" && key != "_escaped_fragment_")
                    {
                        if (key != null)
                        {
                            path += "/" + key + "/" + Request.QueryString[key];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            path +=  "/" + Request.QueryString[key];
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Attention: TabId might be in a different case (TabID), so use case insensitive string comparison.